# Checking if a number is a perfect power

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to know how would I use Mathematica in order to check if the number is a perfect power I saw the algorithm but couldn't grasp it enough to implement it, so can anybody help?

Comment: Well, you could just use `FactorInteger`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function below returns the power of n.

```
power[n_] := GCD @@ (FactorInteger[n][[All, 2]])
```

example:

```
power[3111696]
```

returns `4` because`3111696=2^4*3^4*7^4`

If you deal with very large numbers where `FactorInteger` simply can't help, you could use trial exponents `IntegerQ[n^(1/m)]` for `m=2,3,4,...`.
Where to stop (I mean m) depends on the length of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by tchronis's answer and Leonid's comment I came up with

```
powers[int_] := FactorInteger[int][[All, 2]]
perfectPowerQ[int_] := (GCD @@ powers[int] > 1)
```

`powers` tells you what powers the prime factors are raised to to get the required number while `perfectPowerQ` checks that all these powers are the same.

Comment: I think you have to use GCD as in @tchronis's answer (`GCD@@[powers[int]]>1`). Those factors do not have to be the same. For example, perfectPowerQ[144] gives False using your code.

Comment: Oh, you are right.  Sneaky.  Edited that correction in.