# Efficiently checking whether a number is a perfect power

Tags: compile, number-theory, big-numbers

**Goal**

The goal is to efficiently check whether a number is a perfect power.

**Attempts**

It is possible to check whether a number is a perfect power using `FactorInteger`, as seen in [(42251)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42251), but that method is very slow, especially for large numbers.

Since the upper bound of my list of interest is around `10^18`, I realized that if a number in my list is a perfect power, its power would be at most `59`(= `Floor[Log2[10^18]]`).

Thus I wrote the following code:

```
powerq[in_] := Evaluate[Or @@ Array[FractionalPart[in^(1/Prime[#])] == 0 &, PrimePi[59]]];
read = OpenRead["numbers"];
write = OpenWrite["powers"];
Do[If[powerq[#], Write[write, #], , Break[]]&@Read[read], Infinity]
```

(I am using `Read` and `Write` because my list has approximately 2 billion numbers (~40 GB) and cannot be stored in RAM; I used `FractionalPart` instead of `IntegerQ` because `IntegerQ` does not work symbolically)

This was slow, so I decided to use `Compile`

```
powerqcomp = Compile[{{in, _Integer}},
 Evaluate[
  Or @@ Array[FractionalPart[in^(1/Prime[#])] == 0 &, 
    PrimePi[59]]], CompilationTarget -> "C"]
```

The problem was that the `Compile`d function uses machine real, so it sometimes returns fallacious answer, such as:

```
powerqcomp[2^15]
(* False *)
```

So, I used a different approach.

If a number $n$ can be expressed as $a^b$ ($a$ and $b$ are positive integers and $b > 1$), then $b \leq \log_{2}{n}$. Then, I could check whether there exists $a$ such that $n = a^b$ for at least one $b$.

Since my list consists of large numbers, trying all $a$ from $1$ to $n^{(1/b)}$ is out of the question. Perhaps I could use `BinarySearch`, but then I would need to generate `Range[n^(1/b)]`; I would need to make my own function that performs a binary search.

This is the code I made that uses binary search. It does work, but it is still too slow (and gives `CompiledFunction::cfn` errors sometimes).

```
powerqcomp2 = 
 Compile[{{in, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{up = 10^9, down = 1, 
    blist = Select[{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 
       43, 47, 53, 59}, # <= Log[2, in] &]},
   Catch[Do[
     While[True,
      Which[#^b == in, Throw[True],
         #^b > in, up = #,
         True, down = #
         ] &[Ceiling[(up + down)/2]];
      If[up - down == 1, Break[]]
      ];
     up = 10^9;
     down = 1,
     {b, blist}]; False]]]
```

**Question**

How could one create code that efficiently checks whether a number is a perfect power?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-98-00952-1)?

Comment: @J.M. I read the article, but it seems like _Mathematica_ is not designed to perform operations in there. E.g. separating the mantissa and the exponent from a floating-point number. `MantissaExponent` calculates the mantissa and exponent, which is slower than simple extraction. Plus, bitwise operations are not permitted on floating-point reals in Mma... How could that algorithm be implemented in Mma?

Comment: As there are only a million cubes in the range of interest (and less of higher powers) perhaps you should build a list of all these and only check for exact squares.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I offer the following as a fast way of testing cubic and higher powers

```
primes = Select[Range[59], PrimeQ]
```

Get a list of all the relevant powers up to a specified limit

```
list[nmax_] := Sort[Flatten[Table[Range[2, Floor[nmax^(1/p)]]^p, {p, Drop[primes, 1]}]]];
```

For example

```
list[1000]

(* {8, 27, 32, 64, 125, 128, 216, 243, 343, 512, 729, 1000} *)
```

Define an AssociationMap and Lookup function

```
 asc = AssociationMap[True&, list[10^19]];
 exactpower1 = Lookup[asc, #, False] &;
```

Test it on a million random integers in under a second

```
AbsoluteTiming[Tally[exactpower1 /@ RandomInteger[{10^18, 2*10^18}, {10^6}]]]
(*  {0.678293, {{False, 1000000}}} *)
```

**ADDED**

In combination with a check for higher order powers, the following can rapidly test for possible squares.  It uses the logic described in https://gmplib.org/manual/Perfect-Square-Algorithm.html to make tests modulo various numbers before falling back to a full test involving a square root.

```
exactsquarefull[n_] := IntegerQ[Sqrt[n]]

 maketest[n_] := Module[{list, asc},
  list = Union[Mod[Range[n]^2, n]];
  asc = AssociationMap[True &, list];
  possiblesquare[n] = Lookup[asc, Mod[#, n], False] &]

 maketest /@ {256, 9, 5, 7, 13, 17, 97};

 exactsquare[n_] := 
 possiblesquare[256][n] && possiblesquare[9][n] && 
  possiblesquare[5][n] && possiblesquare[7][n] && 
  possiblesquare[13][n] && possiblesquare[17][n] && 
  possiblesquare[97][n] && exactsquarefull[n]
```

This matches the expected result on all numbers up to 10^6

```
 {exactsquare[#] == exactsquarefull[#]} & /@ Range[1000000] // Union

 (* {{True}} *)
```

and checks 10^6 large numbers in under 3 seconds

```
 AbsoluteTiming[Tally[exactsquare /@ RandomInteger[{10^18, 2*10^18}, {1000000}]]]
 (* {2.76558, {{False, 1000000}}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. However, I think there's a typo in your first definition of `asc`. Shouldn't it have `True &` not `True`?

Comment: @JHM quite correct

Comment: Just to note, the functions `exactpower1` and `exactsquare` both return `False` when a non-Integer argument is used. I fixed it by modifying them so that they only take integers as arguments (i.e. `exactpower1[n_Integer] := ...` and `exactsquare[n_Integer] := ...` )

Answer (score 5):

There is this way:

```
SetAttributes[test, Listable]
test[n_] := FirstPosition[Reverse[#[[2 ;; Ceiling[Length[#]/2]]] &[
                  Divisors[n]]], _?(IntegerQ[Log[#, n]] &), 0] =!= 0
Pick[#, test[#]] &[Range[1000]]
```